# App crash when attempt to run on device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, playscape

I recently integrated `Playscape SDK` and android play services into my Unity (4.5.5) project. Build process for android run without any errors, however when I try to run the app on a device, black screen is shown (no Unity splash screen) and app is closed after few seconds.

Using android `DDMS` I get this error on top:

```
E/CRASH(24508): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics;
```

What could the cause be?

Comment: Did you strip google-play-services.jar file? If yes, please, check if analytics module exists in the jar that you stripped.

Comment: Where did you build your app? Android Studio or Unity Editor?

Answer (score 0):

your `IDE` is not able to find the class in the `GoogleAnalytics` make sure you include the libraries

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Android Studio,  you should check the build.gradle file and see the dependencies list to ensure all the libraries you're using are declared there.  After that sync gradle.  Then Clean Build your project. See if that works.